# Remove line above section

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I always get a line above my custom section view. How can I remove it?

Comment: Could you give a larger view of your UI? It's hard to tell without a  context.

Comment: @user2105505 I've added a larger view of my `UITableView`

Comment: I guess, you are using UIToolbar as a custom section header view. Just set `view.clipsToBounds = YES` in that case to remove the top border

Answer (score 3):

Try this, this code works for me:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
        sectionHeader.hidden = YES;
        return sectionHeader;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want that my section view stays visible, I only want to remove the line above it.

Comment: Try with this: `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

Comment: Or this: `self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: @kova this a a tableView-wide solution. It does not remove the separator from one section, but the entire tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Check the style of your UITableView in the interface builder. If it is grouped, then it will have lines like what you are seeing. If it is plain, it shouldn't. I believe plain is the default setting, so my next guess is that the lines are in fact from the bottom of the UITableViewCell that is on top of the header. Try changing the separator to none or single line etched and see if that changes the line.

EDIT: I setup a default UITableView in the Interface Builder and got this:

[image: Default TableView]

As you can see, there is no line above the section. Otherwise it looks just like yours. My next question would be do you set any properties in your UITableViewController's code? Something like cellHeight or other might affect it, but I don't know for sure. Also try throwing a TableViewController into your storyboard and manually add static sections to it to see if these have the same result.

Comment: There are no lines between the cells when I use that. But I want lines between my cells but no lines above the section.

Comment: Yes, changing the separator to none will remove the lines between your cells. The reason for doing this is to see if it removes the line at the top of your section header. If it does, than that line belongs to the cell. If not, it belongs to something else.

Comment: Yes, it removes the line above the section, when I use Single Line Etched or None.

Comment: I added some new suggestions, but frankly I'm baffled by this issue. I hope one of these new suggestions leads you to a solution or at least reveals some useful information!

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `headerView.clipsToBounds = true` in your viewForHeader method